# How should merges be performed in SVN

Tags: svn, merge

I have a question about SVN merge process.

I have some file modifications in branch1 and I want to merge those changes into branch2, branch3 and trunk.

Should the merge be done from branch1 -> branch2 and then branch2 -> branch3 and finally branch3 -> trunk ?

OR

Should the merge done from branch1 -> (branch2, branch3 and trunk) ?

Comment: To answer this question you're going to need to provide information about the ancestry of each branch.  Are all the branches made off trunk or were some made off other branches?

Comment: All the branches are made out of trunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you merge two (any) nodes in SVN (and also in other /probably *not all*/ SCMs), in most common case target will get **all changes** from source, starting **from the point of divergence** in history

Thus, if you want to populate only changes from branch1 into other nodes, you can

- perform "complete" merge (read `svn help merge`, 1-st form) N times for N targets with the same source - branch1 (most logical and readable later on checking history way)
- perform "complete" merge into one (any) target, use **this mergeset** as source for "cherry-pick" merge for other targets (it will work, will give identical result, but seems as para-logical solution)

PS - "complete" merges with changeable sources leads to the fact that **all** changes from intermediate branches will appear in target branches, i.e for

> then branch2 -> branch3 and finally branch3 -> trunk

- branch3 will get branch1+branch2 changes
- trunk will get branch1+branch2+branch3 changes

instead of sharing changes from branch1 for other offshoots of development

Comment: You shouldn't ever execute merges between sibling branches in Subversion, base selection for future merges can be messed up.  So your first suggestion is just bad advice.  He needs to merge branch1 back to trunk, then do a catch up merge from trunk (pulling changes that didn't come from branch1 if he wants them too) or cherry-pick off trunk into branch2 and branch3.

Comment: @BenReser - "base selection for future merges can be messed up" WTF?! **Show me sample from real-life!!!** And poisoning of trunk by WIP is **BAD IDEA (tm)**. I'm afraid, with such developers Subversion confidently routed to the dustbin of history

Comment: The guy said he wanted to take the changes back to trunk anyway.  So who said anyting about WIP changes.  We actually have almost no idea what his workflow is like since he didn't tell us that.  I also am not saying the situation is ideal, just telling you the way it is.  I'll work up an example here in a bit.  I also really don't appreciate the insult when I'm just trying to point out the state of things.

Comment: Easy case this works exactly as you'd expect: https://paste.apache.org/fQeu  Hard case (branch1 splits a file, that thankfully branch2 and 3 don't touch, otherwise that'll have other conflicts, Java developers see this sort of thing when refactoring a lot) https://paste.apache.org/60cM  This fails because we calculate base wrong for the new file and try to add it again.  Only merging between trunk and branch avoids this: https://paste.apache.org/5I9f  You can also avoid by not svn cp'ing but you lose blame history that way.  Yes this sucks and yes it's due to not having "real" branches.